# Sankey Diagram: is there a way to color the flows according to an extra column in ggsankey?

Tags: r, ggplot2, sankey-diagram

I am making a Sankey diagram with `ggalluvial`.

Here is my dataset

```
library(ggsankey)
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  mtcars %>%
  make_long(cyl, vs, am, gear, carb) %>% 
  mutate(color = c(rep("red", 80), rep("blue", 80)))
```

You can obtain a Sankey diagram like this:

```
df %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = x, 
               next_x = next_x, 
               node = node, 
               next_node = next_node,
               fill = factor(node),
           label = factor(node))) +
  geom_sankey()+
  geom_sankey(flow.alpha = .6,
              node.color = "gray30") +
  geom_sankey_label(size = 3, color = "white", fill = "gray40") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  theme_sankey(base_size = 18) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5))
```

[image]

**Now, I want to color the flows between the labels by the column `color` of the `df`. Is it possible? If not, do you know any other ways to do it in R?**

I tried:

```
df %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = x, 
               next_x = next_x, 
               node = node, 
               next_node = next_node,
               fill = factor(color),
           label = factor(node))) +
  geom_sankey()+
  geom_sankey(flow.alpha = .6,
              node.color = "gray30") +
  geom_sankey_label(size = 3, color = "white", fill = "gray40") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  theme_sankey(base_size = 18) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5))
```

But the plot seems totally broken:

[image]

Comment: please include a list of packages you used. where is the function `make_long()` from

Comment: Good point, it is in the `ggsankey` package

Comment: Nevermind, `ggaluvial` is way better

Comment: if you solved the problem share you solution as an answer to help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, `ggaluvial` seems more adapted to my problem:

Here is the data formating:

```r
df <-
  mtcars %>%
  select(cyl, vs, am, gear, carb) %>% 
  mutate(color = c(rep("red", nrow(mtcars)/2), rep("blue", nrow(mtcars)/2)),
         id = seq(1:nrow(mtcars))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = !c(color, id),
               names_to = "var",
               values_to = "state")
```

And here is the plot with the correct flow colors:

```r
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = var,
               stratum = state,
               label = state,
               alluvium = id)) +
      stat_alluvium(aes(fill = color),
                    width = 0,
                    alpha = 1,
                    geom = "flow")+
      geom_stratum(width = 0.2)+
      geom_text(stat = "stratum", size = 5, angle = 90)+
      theme_bw()
```

[image]